# Hilbert space of multivariate random variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, hilbert-spaces

From [this lecture notes](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/%7Estine/stat910/lectures/16_hilbert.pdf) (Page 7, Example 4), the space of univariate random variables with finite variance is a Hilbert space, when the inner product is chosen as $\langle X, Y \rangle = \mathrm{Cov} (X, Y)$. I'm asking for answers or references for the following two questions:

(1) How to generalize the prescribed idea of constructing Hilbert space to multi-variate random variables?

(2) Can we define a Hilbert space of random variables, with inner product as  $\langle X, Y \rangle = \mathbb{E} (X^T Y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For a multivariate random variable $X = (X_1,\ldots X_d)$, we normally define the expected value of $X$ to be defined to be $\mathbb{E}(X) = (\mathbb{E}(X_1),\ldots \mathbb{E}(X_d))$ and say that a multivariate random variable $X$ has finite variance if $\mathbb{E}[|X - \mathbb{E}[X]|^2]<\infty$ where $|\cdot|$ is the standard $l^2$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$. You can then extend your inner product for $d=1$ to be given by $\left< X,Y\right> = \mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])\cdot (Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])]$, where the $\cdot$ is represents your traditional dot product. This gives the same definition for your definition in $d=1$ but is defined for arbitrary $d$. This function is in fact an inner product and inherits its properties from the expected value operator. This said, I am not sure if there are other inner products on multivariate random variables to reduce to your case if $d=1$.
2. That's exactly how the Hilbert space is defined normally for multivariate random variables.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the quick answer here! For (1), if we define the inner product as the covariance, then $\langle X, X \rangle = \mathbb{E}(X^TX) - (\mathbb{E}(X))^2 = \mathrm{Var}(X)$. However, $\mathrm{Var}(X) = 0$ does not necessarily imply $X= 0 $, which violates the definition of inner product. Did I mistaken something? For (2), this inner product lacks of a term $-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$. Does it change anything?

Comment: Good catch, I made the edit for 1).  For 2), since we have changed the inner product, we have potentially changed the induced topology. A consequence of this is two random variables may be orthogonal with one inner product but not with the other.

Comment: I think the issue for (1) remains after the edit. From $\langle X, X \rangle = 0$, we have $\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}(X)]^2 =0$, which implies $X \equiv \mathbb{E}X$. However, by the definition of inner product, $\langle X, X\rangle = 0$ should imply $X = 0$. Anyway, this may not be a big issue since I'm more interested in confirming (2) is correct.

Comment: That's a good point, then your original inner product cannot actually be an inner product by the same logic.